# RangeColumn: Show difference between two y values as Label

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a RangeColumn with two y values per DataPoint. In the chart I would like to see the datapoint labeled with the difference of the two y values.

I tried:

```
DataPoint p = new DataPoint();
p.SetValueXY(d.Date, prev, prev + biggerResult.Count);
p.Label = biggerResult.Count.ToString();
s_AC_Checked.Points.AddXY(d.Date, prev, prev+biggerResult.Count);
```

Also this is not bringing me further:

```
s_AC_Checked.Label = "#VALY1\n#VALY2\n#VALY2-#VAL1\n#LABEL";
```

No chance to see the difference between the y values.
Here is what appears:

The right column should show "5" as a difference ...

Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Ejn.png

Comment: Indeed this level of 'sophistication' is not supported by the rather rudimantary label expressions. You will need to calculate these values yourself and set the Labels in code.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Doing it after the point was added to the series does the trick ...

```
DataPoint p = new DataPoint();
p.SetValueXY(d.Date, prev, prev + biggerResult.Count);

int index = s_AC_Checked.Points.AddXY(d.Date, prev, prev+biggerResult.Count);
DataPoint pt = s_AC_Checked.Points[index];
pt.Label = biggerResult.Count.ToString();
pt.SetCustomProperty("LabelStyle", "Left");
pt.LabelForeColor = Color.Black;
pt.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```